# PHP array in twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I have this code in php, I converted it in twig but didn't get same result.

```
 <?php for($j=0;$j<sizeof($products[$category]);) { ?>
   <div class="wrapper">
       <?php for($f=0;$f<$rows;$f++,$j++) { 
                if($j<sizeof($products[$category])) { ?>
                    <?php if($products[$category][$j]) { ?>

                    <?php } 
                     if(sizeof($products[$category])<(4*$rows)-1){
                       if(((sizeof($products[$category])-($j)) + 1)%3 == 0){
                              $cnt = 1;
                                }
                                if($cnt == 1){
                                        $f++;
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
```

in twig file:

```
{% for j in 0..(products[category]|length)-1 %}
    <div class="wrapper">
          {% for f in 0..rows-1 %}
                {% if j < products[category]|length %}
                    {% if products[category][j] %}

                    {% endif %} 
                    {% if products[category]|length < ((4*rows)-1) %} 
                        {% if(((products[category]|length)-(j)) + 1)%rows == 0 %}
                                    {% set cnt = 1 %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {% if cnt == 1 %}
                                {% set f = f + 1 %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                 {% endif %}
            {% set j = j + 1 %}
           {% endfor %}  

    </div>
```

How can I implement `$j++` with for loop f iteration?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you do {% set loop.parent.loop.index = loop.parent.loop.index + 1  %} in twig?

Comment: @MantisSupport, Thanks but I didnt get you. Can you please write as per my code variables?

Comment: Cant just do {% set j = j + 1 %} in your 2nd loop? @mantis I do hope that you can't alter the loop variable

Comment: I have done but my problem is when f = rows-1 ,f for loop will be discarded and control moves to j for loop meanwhile when control moves to j for loop I want to increase j++ which cant be achieved by writing  {% set j = j + 1 %} in f for loop as it is not going to executed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this its will work for you

```
<div class="wrapper">
{% set j = 0 %}
{% for f in 0..rows-1 %}
    {% if j < products[category]|length %}
        {% if products[category][j] %}

        {% endif %} 
        {% if products[category]|length < ((4*rows)-1) %}
            {% if(((products[category]|length)-(j)) + 1)%rows == 0 %}
                {% set cnt = 1 %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if cnt == 1 %}
                {% set f = f + 1 %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %} 
    {% if f < rows %}
        {% set j = j + 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: @Prashant, I have tried this but with my PHP code I got result as

1  3  5
2  4

but with twig  I got result as

1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5

so in f for loop it does increase j while move to parent loop on condition check of f for loop as in php

Comment: if(((sizeof($products[$category])-($j)) + 1)%3 == 0){   its different in twig and php code is that issue ?

Comment: No that is not the issue. I just used variable instead of 4 in twig

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169990/discussion-between-prashant-and-radhika).

Answer (score 0):

Writing below code based on the out put you want..

Like - Total Rows 2, items are 6 then

```
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

Rows are 3 and items are 8 then

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6
```

Assuming twig follow - zero based index array

```
{% set TOTALITEMS = (products[category]|length) %}
{% set TOTALROWS = 2 %}
{% set ITEMSPERROW = TOTALITEMS / TOTALROWS %} <!-- make sure you get integer number only, if not then make it by helper functions of php / twig -->

{% for rowIndex in 0 .. TOTALROWS - 1 %}
  <!-- start a div which will contain a row -->

    {% for columnIndex in 0 .. ITEMSPERROW - 1 %}

        <!-- here you have a item ready to dump in html -->
        {%  products[category][ (columnIndex * TOTALROWS) + rowIndex ]  %}

    {% endfor %} <!-- end of loop for columnIndex ...-->

  <!-- end a div which contained a row -->
{% endfor %} <!-- end of loop for rowIndex ...-->
```